# Add tcpdump docker image with base image node:10.0.0

Tags: docker, tcp

How can I add `tcpdump` package in Dockerfile if the base image is `node:10.0.0`

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:10.0.0
EXPOSE $SERVICE_PORT
USER node
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/
WORKDIR /home/node/
COPY package.json /home/node/
RUN npm install
COPY . /home/node/
CMD ["npm", "run", "staging"]
```

I want to trace the traffic in this container.

Answer (score 2):

It is unnecessary to modify your image to access the network of the container. You can run a second container in the same network namespace:

```
docker run -it --net container:${container_to_debug}  nicolaka/netshoot
```

From there, you can run `tcpdump` and a variety of other network debugging tools and see the traffic going to your other container. To see all the tools included in netshoot, see the github repo: https://github.com/nicolaka/netshoot

Answer (score 0):

you base image is debian based, therefore use `apt-get` as your package manager. add to your dockerfile the following instructions:

```
USER root 
RUN apt-get update -y; exit 0
RUN apt-get install tcpdump -y
```

explanation:

**USER root** - apt-get requires root permissions.

**RUN apt-get update -y; exit 0**  - i am adding `exit 0` to tell docker i want to keep the build, even if apt-get couldn't get **all** of its mirror files

**RUN apt-get install tcpdump -y** - installation of the package.